# Does Adobe Muse work with the meteor framework?

Tags: html, meteor, adobe, muse

I am trying to find out if the code output from Adobe Muse would pose any problems with the Meteor framework I am running.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor uses the Blaze templating engine and it expects its views to use that. I don't know how to configure it to use another template library and I suspect you cannot.

However, I believe all Adobe Muse does is generate HTML/CSS and some JS that makes the page look a certain way.  If so, all you need to do is copy/paste the code and ensure that you still use the proper structure of a meteor app. 
Consult for reference: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

As long as the helper methods properly feed data to the view and as long as you display the data using Blaze:

```
{{#each tasks}}
      {{> task}}
{{/each}}
```

You should be fine and everything should display properly.